# Motivation for long exact sequence of group cohomology

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Whenever people with weak abstract algebra backgrounds ask me to explain group cohomolgy, I typically say something along the lines of: "Taking G-invariants is a very natural process. The failure of this process to preserve short exact sequence is sorrowing. To make things better, we fix the short exact sequence in a canonical way with group cohomology."

Recently, however, I've become a bit more dubious of this motivation. Given an exact sequence $0\to A^G\to B^G\to C^G$, fixing it is easy:

$$0\to A^G\to B^G\to C^G\to C^G/\text{Im}\left(B^G\to C^G\right)\to 0.$$

The question is thus

> Why is the cohomology way of fixing exact sequences better than this one? How should I motivate/explain to a beginner that it is important that the term added on the right only depends on the $G$-module structure of $A$, and not on $B$ or $C$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you for your insightful comments. I would push back against your first claim however. You can reconstruct A from the map from B to C, but you can't reconstruct the map from B to C from A. Hence, putting the group H^1(G,A) on the right does use strictly less information

Comment: This way of completing the sequence works tautologically, but it doesn't actually help you to *compute* anything. The point of the LES in group cohomology is that the cohomology groups only depend on the $G$-modules in your sequence, so you can often compute them independently of that sequence and then deduce information about this sequence from them.